# C# Save vs Save As

Tags: save

Situation: You have a simple text editor and you've got the "Save As..." routine down pat with the following code:

```
        SaveFileDialog dlg = new SaveFileDialog();

        dlg.Filter = "Text Files (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files (*.*|*.*";
        dlg.AddExtension = true;
        dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
        dlg.FilterIndex = 1;

        if (dlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            System.IO.TextWriter w = new System.IO.StreamWriter(dlg.FileName.ToString());

            w.Write(textBox1.Text);
            w.Flush();
            w.Close();
```

Now you want to write a routine for "Save" as opposed to "Save As" but aren't sure how to do it. Anyone know?

Comment: Same as "Save As," but using the original filename, with overwrite, without user confirmation.

Answer (score 1):

In order to implement the save feature you need to know which file is open.

Usually the logic is, when you click "save", if the file you are currently processing is an existing file the program attempts to save the contents in that particular file, otherwise ask the user where to save the file, whereas "save as" always asks the user where to save the file.